# How to handle large String Grids?

Tags: delphi

I find that I might have to use a String Grid of less than 10 columns, but about 50k rows.

Experiments have showed it to be a very unresponsive CPU hog.

Any pointers?

Code or components?

Preferably Delphi (7) build in or TMS (for which I have a license) or FOSS (for commercial use).

---

Update: please don't just tell me to use Virtual Tree View, etc. Please tell me why, so that I can learn something. Thanks.

Comment: You should post some code if you wan't to find out why your code is slow.

Comment: first, why do you "need" to load 50k rows, you can only display around 25-50 at once on the screen? second you haven't told us how much memory your system(or virtual machine) has and how much those 50k rows eat, if it requires more than the system memory then the "virtual memory" will come into play and use HDD(or maybe, just maybe your SSD) which is wa-ha-hay slower than the RAM. Don't take my comment as an attack, I'm tryig to understand what's your problem.

Comment: +1 a fair enough question. I can only disply 20-50 rows, but I do "need" the data somewhere. Mayeb I can put it in a DB, rather than the string grid, or maybe I want to keep in in my program, and not use a db.  In either case, I would have two sets of data - the string grid where I keep 50 rows & soemwhere where I keep the rest (or all), and woudl need some tricky code to synch them.  A point well made, which reflects why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the problem came from adding this number to the TStringGrid.

Adding 100k rows took less than 1 second (700ms) (Not high end PC, just Dual Core).

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
Const
  arr : array[1..5] of string = ('One','Two','Three','Four','Five');
  Rows = 100000;
var
  I: Integer;
  F,E : Integer;
begin
  StringGrid1.RowCount := Rows;
  F := GetTickCount;
  for I := 0 to Rows do
  begin
    StringGrid1.Cells[1,I] := Arr[1] + IntToStr(I);
    StringGrid1.Cells[2,I] := Arr[2]+ IntToStr(I);
    StringGrid1.Cells[3,I] := Arr[3]+ IntToStr(I);
    StringGrid1.Cells[4,I] := Arr[4]+ IntToStr(I);
    StringGrid1.Cells[5,I] := Arr[5]+ IntToStr(I);
  end;
  E := GetTickCount;
  ShowMessage(Inttostr(E-F));
end;
```

I think the slowness in your code, do you bring the data from database? if so this is will be the bottleneck of your code, also adding 50k to WHATEVER GRID to show for users called **"Bad practice"**.

And it's hard to tell you why that's slow without showing any code.

Comment: 50K rows are fine if the grid has some kind of filtering built in. It is not always the best / most performant solution to do the filtering on the backend, think OLAP / cubes for example.

Comment: @mjn, u r right, but his questions he asks about adding 50k to normal StringGrid or TMS one, which they are not related to OLAP/Cubes works.

Comment: +1 thanks for coding that (wish I could give more than +1). I think my problem might be using a non db-aware string grid with a db. But will using a db aware grid make things so much better, or will it still be very slow?  Do people normally have problems with 50k row string grids or not?

Comment: @LeonixSolutions, as I said before, showing 50k is really a bad practice, users will never be able to work with much rows as you will show them, but try to load the data first into memory table and see how much that take, then show the data into DBGrid or StringGrid and see the difference.

Answer (score 5):

The TListView component in virtual mode is recommended frequently (I have not tried it myself but it sounds rather easy to implement)

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in virtual treeview you should checkout the whole virtual treeview trunk from http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/source/checkout. You will find Demos\Advanced subdirectory where and Demo application showing the virtual treeview functionality, for example how to use virtual treeview as a grid.

You need SVN to checkout the code from googlecode. If you have never used SVN download and install [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at Virtual Treeview, which is built for high volume:
http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=38

Comment: +1 Darian, I apologize. It might look like I updated the question in reponse to your post, which you might think insulting. In fact, it just occurred to me that some folks might just say "use X" without a reson, which is of less help to me and others who read this question (it woudl help if we understood why). I didn't see your answer until after I had editted the question (and you did say that it is build for high volume).

Comment: Thansk, Darian, I had searched and read good things about it, but hadn't checked it out as it is called Tree View and I wanted a grid - more fool me.

Comment: +1 I would say Virtual Tree View is the best you can get. If you check the screenshots on the Soft Gems website you can see the various "display modes" of this component - including string grid view.